# How to use symmetric key to encrypt and sign SOAP using WSS4J

Tags: java, web-services, encryption, soap, wss4j

I need to build web-service client application using `Axis 1.4` that will access third party system (Web service Producer).

In order to send valid request to third party system I need to **encrypt** and **sign** the `SOAP request` before sending it to them.

I make use of `wss4j 1.5` to do this task where I follow the steps in this link: 
[Calling an OWSM protected service with Axis 1.4 and WSS4J](http://biemond.blogspot.com/2011/09/calling-owsm-protected-service-with.html)

What I understand that:

1- To **encrypt** the `SOAP` I need to use third party public key and they will decrypt it using their own private key.

2- To **sign** the `SOAP` I need to use my own private key and they should verify the signature using my public key that I need to share it with them.

I did that but I am receiving the error

```
  faultString: Did not understand "MustUnderstand" header(s)
```

From third party end. After checking with third party team they said:

"***We use “Username authentication with symmetric key”, so we do not maintain any client certificates at our trust store. There is a single shared key used for both signing and encryption. Hence you need to do signing and encryption using our certificate.***"

This response does not make sense to me. I understand that I need to use third party certificate (i.e. public key) to **encrypt** the `SOAP Request`.

But how can I use the same public key - *which is the only certificate shared by them - to sign `SOAP Request`* ?

I believe I need a private key in order to do that.

Do I need their private key to do that? Any clarification will be helpful.

Comment: Since they said they dont maintain your certificates, get a key from them and encrypt the request with that .

Comment: @primitiveType I did asked them for the key file again. But no luck, they still Insisting that I do not need any file other than their public certificate. At this point I want to know who is mistaken? Where is the misunderstanding? Do I really need their private key ?